# How to run tests in an Angular CLI project from a subdirectory?

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, typescript, karma-runner

I have an Angular CLI project, which is a large single-page app. This app is divided into multiple feature modules that are lazily loaded.

What I'd like to be able to do is to go into the subdirectory of one of my modules and run just the tests for that module. The idea is to have our CI server be able to detect which module(s) have changed and only run the tests for those module(s).

Is there a way to do this? I tried running `ng test` from within the module subdirectory, but that didn't seem to do it. Hopefully there is a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

A quick hack for this may be to change all your tests from it( to xit(  this will exclude them from the test.